# Deliver component from 1 stream to another using scm

Tags: rtc, maven-scm, ibm-jazz, scmmanager

I need to deliver selected component from Stream 'A' to Stream 'B' through RTC scm commands.
Could anyone suggest the combination of scm cmd required to deliver these changes. 
I have performed this task using build definition. 
Please answer related to scm cmd only

Answer (score 0):

You don't deliver a component from a stream, you are delivering a change set from a repo workspace to a stream.

See [deliver example](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Fdeliver_ex.html):

> Deliver changeset `1764` from workspace "`accept1`" to stream "`abcStream1`"

```
C:\local-workspaces\HelloJazz>scm deliver 1764 -s 1353 -t 1354
Delivering changes:
  Repository: https://localhost:9443/jazz/
  Workspace: (1354) "abcStream1"
    Component: (1365) "accept1 Default Component"
      Change sets:
        (1764) ---$  "No comment" 20-Aug-2014 10:14 PM
          Changes:
            ---c- \10\10.txt
Deliver command successfully completed.
```

See more in those [`scm` commands examples](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCP65_6.0.4/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/m_cli_usecases.html).

Comment: In build definition,under post build tab, we have set flow target option to send selected component to another stream. Similar thing I want to do through scm. Please help with that

Comment: @RaviYadav I haven't found much so far: https://jazz.net/forum/questions/159544/command-to-use-in-post-build-command-line